# How to show a relation between two persons in a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I want to show a relation between two persons in a datagridview (C# Windowsforms).

So, I made a (MS Access) table with persons. Each person has an unique number as its PK. Thereafter I made a Relation table. In this table I have a column for person 1 (FK), a column for the relation and a column for person 2 (FK).

This looks like this:

[image: ERD]

Now I tried to show this in a datagridview with columns that show `Fname`, `Lname`, `DOB`, `Relation`, `Fname`, `Lname`, `DOB`. I tried a lot, but I can't let it work.

I hope someone can let me know how the (SQL) `select` query should look like or what I should do to make this work.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use two references of your `Person` table in your query, since, for each record in your `Relation` table, **two separate records** are to be displayed from your `Person` table.

Therefore, you'll need to use a query along the lines of:

```sql
select
    p1.fname, 
    p1.lname, 
    p1.dob, 
    r.relation,
    p2.fname, 
    p2.lname, 
    p2.dob
from
    (relation r inner join person p1 on r.pnumber1 = p1.pnumber) 
    inner join 
    person p2 on r.pnumber2 = p2.pnumber
```